# Redirecting port with Docker and Hyper-V

Tags: docker, hyper-v

With virtualbox i can redirect a port through this menu: 
[image]

Is there something similar that i can do in Docker for windows while using Hyper-V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible.

To expose a container’s internal port, you can start the container with the -P or -p flag. The exposed port is accessible on the host and the ports are available to any client that can reach the host.

example 
`docker run -d -p 8080:80 my_image nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

your port 8080 in the host will be mapped to container internal port 80.

Comment: I guess that is the sensible answer. 
What i wanted to do originally on my post might not be necessary, since with Hyper-V the connectivity is already made.